# Run a Jupyter Notebook with space in relative path from another notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hi im try to run a notebook from another notebook, the name of the notebook that i want to run is prepracion.ipynb from folder Procesamiento.

when i try this code:

```
%run Procesamiento\\Preparacion.ipynb
```

this is the result:

```
Exception: File `'Procesamiento.ipynb.py'` not found.
```

i dont know what im doing bad. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`) and preced the path with a dot (`.`) (indicating file path to be the current directory where the current notebook is located).

If the name has spaces in it as I understood. Put path between quotes:

```
%run ./"Processamiento con espacio"/Preparacion.ipynb
```

or

```
%run "./Processamiento  con espacio/Preparacion.ipynb"
```

**The code below is what you want:**

```
%run ./Processamiento/Preparacion.ipynb
```

This should work when you start jupyter notebooks from the filesystem.